# Highlight Goto in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am currently translating old generated C# code which is full of **goto**. Please dont comment on that, I know its horrible. 
Anyway, is there a way / extension / whatever to make goto-statements more readable? Its a pain to find the place where the code jumps to. I dont want to use the search-function since it makes me lose my orientation.

All I found is this:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b286b9c-4dd5-416b-b143-e31d36dc622b
and it doesnt work.

Can you recommend anything?

Comment: Isn't the bad readability the exactly the reason why we avoid using `goto`?

Comment: Well, I think there is a think to try, use Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->Indentation->Label Indentation->Place goto labels in leftmost column, that will atleast make all labels quickly noticable.

Comment: The extension you've mentioned is for navigation between symbols in code, not for finding GOTO statements.

Comment: @Aschratt You should read what I wrote. Im not planning on using goto, but i need help to get rid of it and a part of this process is to make this stuff mroe readable first.

Comment: @CSharpie: I understood what you wrote... it was just an rhetoric question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ReSharper's [Navigate to function exits](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__Navigate_from_Here__Function_Exits.html).

Or Coderush's [flow break icons](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument3527)

Answer (score 3):

A bit late maybe, but you can build your own using Visual Studio Extensibility (and therefore add custom behavior as well): [Inside the Editor: Tags and Classifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd885240.aspx#tagsandclassifiers). The steps are:

1) Create an Editor Classifier project (builtin project type)

2) Delete the existing class files

3) Add the code below. It will colorize all 'goto' statements in code portions in red:

[image: goto colorizer]

```
internal class GotoTagger : ITagger<GotoTag>
{
    private ITextSearchService _textSearchService;
    private ITextStructureNavigator _textStructureNavigator;

    event EventHandler<SnapshotSpanEventArgs> ITagger<GotoTag>.TagsChanged { add { } remove { } }

    public GotoTagger(ITextSearchService textSearchService, ITextStructureNavigator textStructureNavigator)
    {
        _textSearchService = textSearchService;
        _textStructureNavigator = textStructureNavigator;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ITagSpan<GotoTag>> GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)
    {
        if (spans.Count == 0)
            yield break;

        if (spans.Count > 0)
        {
            // look for 'goto' occurrences
            foreach (SnapshotSpan span in _textSearchService.FindAll(new FindData("goto", spans[0].Snapshot, FindOptions.WholeWord | FindOptions.MatchCase, _textStructureNavigator)))
            {
                yield return new TagSpan<GotoTag>(span, new GotoTag());
            }
        }
    }
}


    [Export(typeof(IViewTaggerProvider))]
    [TagType(typeof(TextMarkerTag))]
    [ContentType("code")] // only for code portion. Could be changed to csharp to colorize only C# code for example
    internal class GotoTaggerProvider : IViewTaggerProvider
    {
        [Import]
        internal ITextSearchService TextSearchService { get; set; }

        [Import]
        internal ITextStructureNavigatorSelectorService TextStructureNavigatorSelector { get; set; }

        public ITagger<T> CreateTagger<T>(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer buffer) where T : ITag
        {
            if (textView.TextBuffer != buffer)
                return null;

            return new GotoTagger(TextSearchService, TextStructureNavigatorSelector.GetTextStructureNavigator(buffer)) as ITagger<T>;
        }
    }

    internal class GotoTag : TextMarkerTag
    {
        public GotoTag() : base("goto") { }
    }

    [Export(typeof(EditorFormatDefinition))]
    [Name("goto")]
    [UserVisible(true)]
    internal class GotoFormatDefinition : MarkerFormatDefinition
    {
        public GotoFormatDefinition()
        {
            BackgroundColor = Colors.Red;
            ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
            DisplayName = "Goto Word";
            ZOrder = 5;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its more about the line where it goes to. Still Ill keep your code since i got some more ideas now.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider [DevExpress CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/). `goto` statements will get an arrow like this: [image: goto arrow]. Hovering over the arrow highlights the statement following the label (if it's already visible), and clicking it makes it visible and moves the cursor to that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Also note, that you can use "Ctrl" + "-" to jump back to the last place in the code, you were looking at. 
This is probably very obvious, but it seemed to me like CSharpie might be unaware of this hotkey.

Comment: I know, thanks. The main reason is that is so hard to figure out what the code does. Jumping back to the start helps though but in nested things it doesnt helpt to find out whats going on.